# ¿Porque devuelvo iQueryable en lugar de una instancia de mi clase?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error a la hora de devolver un objeto al validar el inicio de sesión:

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Linq.IQueryable'' en 'Negocio.clsUsuario.ValidarSesionU'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)

Mi Código es el siguiente:

```
public class ValidarSesionU
{
    public Int64 usu_IDUsuario { get; set; }
    public string usu_nombre { get; set; }
    public Int32 usu_IDRol { get; set; }
}

public ValidarSesionU ValidarSesion(string stUsuario, string stPassword)
{
    try
    {
        using (BDGestionReclamosEntities BD = new BDGestionReclamosEntities())
        {
            var iqValidarSesion = from x in BD.Usuario
                                  where x.usu_nombre == stUsuario && x.usu_contraseña == stPassword
                                  select new ValidarSesionU
                                  {
                                      usu_IDUsuario = x.usu_IDUsuario,
                                      usu_nombre = x.usu_nombre,
                                      usu_IDRol = x.usu_IDRol
                                  };

            return iqValidarSesion; //ACÁ DEVUELVE EL ERROR
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

De la única forma que pude resolverlo es convirtiendo el objeto a `List`:

```
public List<ValidarSesionU> ValidarSesion(string stUsuario, string stPassword)
{
    try
    {
        using (BDGestionReclamosEntities BD = new BDGestionReclamosEntities())
        {
            var iqValidarSesion = from x in BD.Usuario
                                  where x.usu_nombre == stUsuario && x.usu_contraseña == stPassword
                                  select new ValidarSesionU
                                  {
                                      usu_IDUsuario = x.usu_IDUsuario,
                                      usu_nombre = x.usu_nombre,
                                      usu_IDRol = x.usu_IDRol
                                  };

            return iqValidarSesion.ToList<ValidarSesionU>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Pero mi intención es devolver un objeto, no una lista, ya que es 1 solo registro el que debe devolver.

¿De qué manera puedo realizar la conversión para que me devuelva objeto y no lista?

> FINALMENTE ASÍ QUEDO MI CÓDIGO:

```
        public class ValidarSesionU
    {
        public Int64 usu_IDUsuario { get; set; }
        public string usu_nombre { get; set; }
        public Int32 usu_IDRol { get; set; }
        public string usu_Password { get; set; }

    }

    public ValidarSesionU ValidarSesion(string stUsuario, string stPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            using (BDGestionReclamosEntities BD = new BDGestionReclamosEntities())
            {
                var iqValidarSesion = from x in BD.Usuario
                                      select new ValidarSesionU
                                      {
                                          usu_IDUsuario = x.usu_IDUsuario,
                                          usu_nombre = x.usu_nombre,
                                          usu_IDRol = x.usu_IDRol,
                                          usu_Password = x.usu_contraseña
                                      };

                return iqValidarSesion.FirstOrDefault(x => x.usu_nombre == stUsuario && x.usu_Password == stPassword);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Es exactamente por eso.. en tu consulta estas aplicando el condicional `WHERE` el cual te devuelve un listado de todos los objetos coincidentes con tu filtro.. debes utilizar `Find`, `FirstOrDefault`, `LastOrDefault` dependiendo lo que necesites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te explico, cuando usas Linq To Entities, tenes la posibilidad de armar una query pasando por varios estados, gracias a la interfaz `iQueryable<T>`

Para explicarme, voy a usar un poco de código.

```
//Contexto que se usará
var context = new Context();

//Una condición que siempre será necesaria
iQueryable<TuClase> query = context.TuClase.Where(x => x.Col1 == 1);

//Basado en un if, podría (o no) existir una segunda condición
if(a>b){
query.Where(x => x.Col2 > 10);
}
//Aún la query no se ejecuta, se ejecutará ahora
List<TuClase> lista = query.ToList();
```

Ahora, entendiendo esto, en tu caso particular, podes usar 6 métodos para que tu objeto se convierta de un `iQueryable<ValidarSesionU>` a un `ValidarSesionU`

1. [**FirstOrDefault()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__): usar cuando el resultado puede ser `null`, `1` o `n` registros, en caso de que la consulta, no devuelva ningún elemento, el resultado será `null`, en caso de responder `n` elementos se obtendrá el primero.
2. [**First()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__): usar cuando el resultado puede ser `1` o muchos, en caso de que el resultado sean muchos, obtendrá el primero, en caso de ser nulo, generará una excepción.
3. [**SingleOrDefault()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SingleOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__): usar cuando el resultado esperado puede ser `1` o `0` (`null`), en caso de ser múltiples elementos, generara una excepción.
4. [**Single()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Single__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__): usar cuando se espera SÍ o SÍ un resultado, en caso de que se reciba, ya sea `null` o múltiples elementos, se disparará una excepción..

Además de los 4 que mencioné existen también [**Last()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Last__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) y [**LastOrDefault()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) que funcionan exactamente igual que los antes mencionados `First()` y `FirstOrDefault()`, sólo que el elemento de devuelve, es el último no el primero.

Por lo cual, en tu ejemplo, en lugar de usar

```
return iqValidarSesion;
```

podrías usar

```
return iqValidarSesion.FirstOrDefault();
```

o cualquiera de los otros 6 métodos mencionados según el caso

Comment: Cabe mencionar que no se necesita un `Where` si se usa la sintaxis de lambda, `FirstOrDefault` tiene una sobrecarga que permite filtrar el primer elemento que cumpla con las condiciones: `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nombre == miNombre);`.

Comment: @NaCl buen dato, realmente no lo sabía :D

Comment: Hola, muy buena información y de gran ayuda, eso significa que el query no se ejecuta, puedo agregarle y quitarle cosas y asi mismo se van agregando esas modificaciones al query, solo hasta que invoco al ToList() se ejecutaría el query.