# El operador '==' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo string y grupo de métodos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Estoy desarrollando mi primer CRUD en **ASP.NET MVC** utilizando **Entity Framework** estoy implementando la función editar pero estoy presentando un error al momento de buscar el servicio mediante su ID

```
public ActionResult EditService(TK_CT_SERVICES service)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
                {

                    TK_CT_SERVICES serv = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Where(services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID == service);                    
                    serv.NAME = service.NAME;
                    serv.CONTENT = service.CONTENT;
                    serv.TK_CT_AREAS_ID = service.TK_CT_AREAS_ID;
                    serv.ENABLED = service.ENABLED;

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //Despues de realizar un cambio al servicio
                    //redireccionamos al index (vista de todo el catalogo de servicios)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

El error lo presento sobre el where

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo claro que **TK_CT_SERVICES_ID** es de tipo string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu código tiene dos errores a simple vista, el primero:

> El operador '==' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'string' y
>   'TK_CT_SERVICES'

Esto es verdad, y se dá al intentar chequear la igualdad entre dos tipos distintos.

Dentro de tu `Where` estas comparando `services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID` con `service`

De un lado de la igualdad, tenemos la lambda, que representa la propiedad (`string`) `TK_CT_SERVICES_ID` de la clase `TK_CT_SERVICES`, pero del lado derecho, sólo tenemos una instancia de la clase `TK_CT_SERVICES`, lo que produce que sea una comparación invalida, ya que ambos tipos son distintos y no tienen definido un método de comparación.

Por otro lado, ya corrigiendo tu error:

```
TK_CT_SERVICES serv = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Where(services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID == service.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID);
```

Este código seguiría teniendo un problema, ya que el resultado de un `Where` a un `DbContext` no devolverá un objeto de tipo `TK_CT_SERVICES` sino, que devolverá un objeto de tipo `IQueryable<TK_CT_SERVICES>`, ya que la query no se ha ejecutado a esta altura..

¿Cómo ejecutarla?

Podemos usar, por ejemplo [`First()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.First%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) o [`Single()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Single%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) entre otros.

Por lo que el resultado final sería

```
TK_CT_SERVICES serv = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Where(services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID == service.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID).First();
```

Te recomiendo que leas esta [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196711/porque-devuelvo-iqueryable-en-lugar-de-una-instancia-de-mi-clase/196718#196718) donde explico lo relacionado al momento de la ejecución de la query (el objeto IQueryable) que te menciono arriba.

Saludos!

Comment: Cabe mencionar que las expresiones lamda pueden ir directamente en la clausulas First, FirstOrDefault, etc.. algo así como db.TK_CT_SERVICES.First(services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID == service.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID)

Comment: @KodiakMx exacto, gracias por acotarlo!.. No lo mencione en la respuesta porque sentí que se estaba haciendo larga de más

Answer (score 3):

Estas comparando una propiedad de tipo string vs tu clase completa. Intenta con:

```
TK_CT_SERVICES serv = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Where(services => services.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID == service.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID);
```

Comment: Con esa solución que me das genera otro error que dice _Ya existe una conversión explicita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)_, si es necesario me avisas y actualizo la pregunta con el nuevo error que me genera

Comment: en que parte te da el error?